# Terraform - Dict with values as list convert to string

Tags: terraform

```
dataset_bindings = {
    "infra":[
      "group:infra-team@xxxx.com",
    ],
    "finance":[
      "group:finance-data@xxx.com",
    ],
    "marketing": [
       "group:marketing@xxx.com"
    ]
   }
```

How can I get all the emails as string. I need to loop thru the dict and get the values and convert those values to string.

Comment: I've noticed that all almost your questions got answered yet not a single answer was accepted. Accepting useful answers is not only a good practice, but reduces duplicates and increases chances of your questions being actually answered.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with `values` and `flatten`:

```
locals {
   dataset_bindings = {
    "infra":[
      "group:infra-team@xxxx.com",
    ],
    "finance":[
      "group:finance-data@xxx.com",
    ],
    "marketing": [
       "group:marketing@xxx.com"
    ]
   }
   
   list_of_emails = flatten(values(local.dataset_bindings))        
}
```

results in:

```
list_of_emails = [
  "group:finance-data@xxx.com",
  "group:infra-team@xxxx.com",
  "group:marketing@xxx.com",
]
```